# Harmonic conjugate of $u(x,y)= x^{2}-y\cdot (y+1)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Can anyone in detail explain  the procedure for finding the harmonic conjugate of the function $$u(x,y) = x^{2} - y\cdot (y+1)$$

I am new to this and I would like to know.

Comment: Did you try anything? Have you set up some equations? Are you having trouble solving those equations?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Yes. I used the C-R equations $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} =\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ and $u_{y}=-v_{x}$.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff But i don't know what I should do after usingt the CR equation.

Answer (score 1):

Following Peter Tamaroff's solution (integration of $v_y=u_x=2x$ and $v_x=-u_y=2y+1$) one obtains $v(x,y)=2xy+f(x)$ and $v(x,y)=2xy+x+g(y)$, from where $v(x,y)=2xy+x+c$ where $c$ is a constant. This is the general form of harmonic conjugate.

With some fluency in complex arithmetics, you can solve the problem with less effort by recognizing $x^2-y^2$ as $\operatorname{Re}(z^2)$ and $-y$ as $\operatorname{Re}(iz)$. Since $u=\operatorname{Re}(z^2+iz)$, we get a harmonic conjugate as $\operatorname{Im}(z^2+iz) = 2xy+x$, up to an additive constant.

Comment: Oh my, thanks for catching that. How silly... can't recall what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so $$u_x(x,y)=2x$$ and $$u_y(x,y)=-2y-1$$

This means that $v_y(x,y)=2x$ and $v_x(x,y)=2y+1$. Integrating w.r.t to $y$ and $x$ respectively you get that $$v(x,y)=2xy+h(x)+C$$ $$v(x,y)=2xy+x+f(y)$$  thus $v(x,y)=2xy+x+C$, $C$ some constant.

Comment: is $V(y)=y(y+1)$ and $U(x)=x^{2})$

Comment: You integrated $v_x$ and $v_y$ with respect to wrong variables, essentially coming back to $u$. Also, the formula after "This means that" could have any constant on the left.